# Windows Mobile 5.0 Button Style

Tags: visual-studio-2008, button, styles, windows-mobile-5.0

I'm currently working on a project using Windows Mobile 5.0 (I know i'ts preety outdated, but it is for industrial PDAs and I'm stuck with it) and I was wondering if is there anyway to change  the style of my application (buttons, treeviews...) so my app doesn't seem so it's just a bunch of boxes with names on them.

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2008 on a Win7 machine if that's any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stock windows elements can only be changed by subclassing them and extending there Paint method. There are many examples and frameworks out there to do so. For example buttons with images or irregullar shapes.

You may also use html and then use a common framework like Jo to have a GUI looking like Android.

Subclassing Controls: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229681%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Layout-Managers: http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2010/07/17/mobile-development-using-layout-managers/

Jo and PhoneGap: http://joapp.com/ (needs html5 browser like zetaKey [http://www.zetakey.com/index.php])